# Installing Ubuntu fails - HP Pavilion T3000

Tags: 12.04, boot, system-installation, hp

Any suggestions on how to get Ubuntu onto this PC?

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a desktop computer that ran WinXP flawlessly - at least a couple of minutes ago.

Now, I've tried running live CDs with the option *Try Ubuntu without installing* for the following releases:

- Linux Ubuntu 12.04. - Test instance fails / the screen goes black after option screen
- Linux Ubuntu 13.10. - Test instance fails / the screen goes black after option screen
- Linux Ubuntu 09.10. - Test instance fails ... with some nasty error
  messages (see photo below)

When - with Ubuntu 09.10. - I ran *Check disk for defects* it actually found two errors, but that's just a side note.

Further Details: Computer is a HP Pavilion T3000.
Here's a photo of the error messages:

[image]

Comment: In order to answer your question, I have a few questions of my own: - Did you download the image for the LiveCDs over a wifi or dial-up connection? - Did you check the MD5/SHA1 of the images you put on these CDs against what they actually should be? - Did you burn the images using a known good system/burner drive/optical media? - Is the CD/DVD drive in the system you are trying to install to currently verified as functioning properly? - Have you checked the physical connection from the CD/DVD drive in the system you are trying to install to? - Is the memory/CPU in the system you are trying to

Comment: This looks like a memory error or a defective disk image. Can you run memtest?

Comment: @Renan Ok, memtest - "test memory" from the live CD menu - has been running for 15+ minutes, no errors so far.

Comment: @olderthandirt here are the answers: all images were downloaded via wifi - burned with brasero in ubuntu 12.10. and "no" is the answer to the other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why I got all the error messages.

**But the workaround that worked was to install Ubuntu instead of opting "Test Ubuntu without installing**".

Once installed Ubuntu 09.10. has been running stable so far. Just to be sure I checked the hdd for bad blocks but there were non. My next step will be to upgrade to 12.04. (current LTS version) via the update manager.

Thank you for the suggestions how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I do not have the ability to comment or edit (mod please fix this), but I can tell you that you have too many variables and some of them should be addressed.

Start with the LiveCD images downloaded over WiFi: Download one over a directly connected machine, or if that is not possible then check the MD5/SHA1 of the image against what you should have gotten.  Start there, then let us know if you have acquired known good images. Check the physical connections on the target machine. Next, burn them then check the burn and again verify that it has been burned properly and without error.

Let us know where you stand after that is done please.

Comment: Hi OTD, you will gain ability to comment or edit with reputation points (you get points for actions on these pages).  Don't worry about it, just leave your reply as an answer, currently.  And Ok, tomorrow I will follow your instructions and post the result as a comment on your answer.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation yet to comment or edit, it's not something the mods can fix. Please read [Privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) and [Reputation](http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation) for details.

Comment: Hi RGS. Went through all the points: ethernet download, MD5 check, physical connections (even inside the pc), tried installing via CD as well as USB stick. Unfortunately, nothing worked and I got the same error messages.